# "Ambigous" equivalent conversions - can I make the compiler just choose any?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I have a template for a class that simulates pointer behavior, returning a pointer to a given stored memory location when cast to any pointer type.

It has operators of conversion to several types (intptr_t, native pointer it's simulating, etc), as normal for pointers, and it returns values a real pointer would return in that case.

```
MockPointer<int> TestIntPointer;
MockPointer<int> TestIntPointer2;

int* a = nullptr;
ASSERT_TRUE(TestIntPointer == a);
ASSERT_TRUE(TestIntPointer == TestIntPointer2);
```

Without `bool operator==(MockPointer<T> rhs)` I'm getting an error at the second assert:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- operator==(int*, int*) <built-in>
- candidates are:
- in expansion of macro 'ASSERT_TRUE'
- operator==(intptr_t {aka long int}, intptr_t {aka long int}) <built-in>
- operator==(intptr_t {aka long int}, int) <built-in>
- operator==(int, intptr_t {aka long int}) <built-in>
- operator==(int, int) <built-in>
 ambiguous overload for 'operator==' (operand types are '{anonymous}::MockPointer<int> and '{anonymous}::MockPointer<int>)
```

With the operator the first assert fails:

```
- in expansion of macro 'ASSERT_TRUE'
- ambiguous overload for 'operator==' (operand types are '{anonymous}::MockPointer<int>' and 'int*')
- candidates are:
- operator==(int*, int*) <built-in>
```

I know there is a bunch of ways to convert the variable and compare it! All of them work the same for the purpose of comparison! Can I force the compiler somehow to pick the first available conversion and go with it instead of complaining that it can't decide whether it should take sugar and milk with its tea, or rather milk and sugar?

edit: complete code (the Operator== lines are near 2/3 of the file, some commented out):

```
    #pragma once

    #include <stdint.h>     //zapewnia stdint_t, specjalny int do przechowywania wskaźników.

    #include "api/utils/tinyutils.h"
    #include "api/standard_exceptions.h"

    namespace Api {

    /**
     * ShmPointer
     * Klasa zachowująca się jak zwykły wskaźnik ale działająca dla w pamięci współdzielonej.
     *
     * Sposób użycia:
     * Każda instancja (wariant) pamięci współdzielonej tworzona jest bądź pobierana przez ShmProvider
     * W szczególności określona instancja to
     *
     *      ShmProvider<typ_shm, klucz_shm> MyShmProvider;
     *
     * Dla niej generujemy template pointerów do wszystkiego, co można w tejże pamięci znaleźć:
     *
     *      template <class T>using MyShmPointer = ShmPointer<T,MyShmProvider>;
     *
     *      Potem już tylko:
     *      MyShmPointer<Grupa> gr = &(MyShmProvider::Base->Grupy[5]);  //cast zwykłego wskaźnika na ShmPointer
     *
     *      MyShmProvider::Base->AktywnaGrupa = gr;     //przypisanie jednego ShmPointer do drugiego, leżącego w SHM
     *
     *      // w zupełnie innym programie
     *      display(MyShmProvider::Base->AktywnaGrupa->kolor);  //odczytanie wartości po wskaźniku
     */
    template<class T, class ShmProvider>
    class ShmPointer
    {
    private:
        int offset = -1;

        bool IsEmpty() const {
            return offset == -1;
        }

        T* MyAddress() {
            if(unlikely(IsEmpty()))
                return nullptr;

            return (T*)((char*)ShmProvider::Base + offset);
        }

        T* Add(int count) {
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>((char*)MyAddress() + count*sizeof(T));
        }
    public:
        ShmPointer() = default;

        //Konstruktor na podstawie wskaźnika.
        ShmPointer(T* shmaddr) : offset((char*)shmaddr - (char*)ShmProvider::Base) {
        }

        // Operatory rzutowania

        //Cast na typ "wskaźnik do T"
        operator T*() {
            return MyAddress();
        }

        //Cast na typ boolean
        operator bool() {
            return !IsEmpty();
        }

        //rzutowanie na int
        operator intptr_t() {
            return (intptr_t) MyAddress();
        }

        // Standardowe operatory (znaczki)

        //Dereferencja na pole
        T* operator->()
        {
            if(IsEmpty()) throw( NullPointerDereferenceException(LOCATION) );

            return MyAddress();
        }

        //Dereferncja wprost
        T& operator*()
        {
            if(IsEmpty()) throw( NullPointerDereferenceException(LOCATION) );
            return *(MyAddress());
        }

        //Przypisanie
        T* operator=(T* shmaddr)
        {
            if(shmaddr==nullptr)
            {
                offset=-1;
                return nullptr;
            }

            offset = (char*)shmaddr - (char*)ShmProvider::Base;
            return MyAddress();
        }

        //Dereferencja nawiasami
        T& operator[](int ndx)
        {
            if(IsEmpty()) throw(NullPointerDereferenceException(LOCATION));

            return (T&) *(Add(ndx));
        }

        T* operator+(int ndx)
        {
            if(IsEmpty())
                return nullptr;

            return Add(ndx);
        }

        T* operator-(int arg)
        {
            if(IsEmpty())
                return nullptr;

            return Add(-arg);
        }

        intptr_t operator-(T* arg)
        {
            if(MyAddress() == nullptr){ return 0; }

            return (intptr_t)((char*)MyAddress() - (char*)arg);
        }

        bool operator!()
        {
            return offset == -1;
        }

        bool operator==(const Api::ShmPointer<T, ShmProvider>& rhs) const {
            return offset == rhs.offset;
        }

        bool operator==(const std::nullptr_t rhs) const {
            return IsEmpty();
        }
    /*
        bool operator==(const T* rhs) const {
            return (MyAddress() == rhs);
        }
    */
        /*
        bool operator!=(const ShmPointer<T, ShmProvider>& rhs) const {
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }
    */
        bool operator!=(const std::nullptr_t rhs) const {
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }
    /*
        bool operator!=(const T* rhs) const {
            return !(MyAddress() == rhs);
        }
    */
        T* operator++()
        {
            if(IsEmpty())
                return nullptr;

            offset += sizeof(T);
            return MyAddress();
        }

        T* operator++(int)
        {
            if(IsEmpty())
                return nullptr;

            T* dummy = MyAddress();
            offset += sizeof(T);
            return dummy;
        }

        T* operator--()
        {
            if(IsEmpty()) return nullptr;
            offset -= sizeof(T);
            return MyAddress();
        }

        T* operator--(int)
        {
            if(IsEmpty()) return nullptr;
            T* dummy = MyAddress();
            offset -= sizeof(T);
            return dummy;
        }

    };

    }
```

Comment: In a word, no. That's what the `operator==(const MockPointer<T>&)` is for; it provides the compiler with a match without having to make any conversions. As soon as the compiler has to make conversions, the function call becomes ambiguous because the compiler does not know that you intend all of these comparisons to be equivalent, and cannot simply "pick" one.

Comment: @Andrew: And that ires me to no end - that I can't just tell it they are equivalent or choose a preferred one. All that type guessing meant to make programmer's life easier boils down to a big fat failure when the artificial intelligence can't be manually overridden. (obviously adding more operator== variants only adds to the ambiguities.)

Comment: This is why I avoid conversion operators. Although in your case, you want the thing to act like a pointer in contexts where a pointer is expected, so there's not much of an alkternative. However, there is a simple solution - define the comparison operator for your type, to prevent the compiler attempting any conversions that would result in ambiguity.

Comment: @Andrew: That's what breaks the first assert. With the comparison operator, while I can compare my "special" pointers just fine, the compiler starts wondering whether to convert real pointer to mine or vice versa. And if I define a comparison of my type to the native pointer type, it only adds one more 'candidate' to the list (despite apparently being a perfect match).

Comment: can you provide the complete definition of `MockPointer`?

Comment: @SF. a perfect match should be chosen if it exists. Would you care to post what conversion functions/implicit constructors you declare and the "perfect" comparison you are trying?

Comment: Looks like you just need to make your constructor `explicit` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73300327b4fcfac8 (removing the "explicit" keyword produces the error you describe).

Comment: Making the constructor `explicit` should work fine, but maybe that gives you uglier syntax for use cases of your class. Without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to tell, but I'd think that making your comparison operators non-member functions, removing the implicit conversion to `intptr_t` and having a comparison to `T*` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an abundance of conversion operators and implicit conversions via constructors. You should be able to avoid the ambiguity by

1. providing a comparison operator that is a perfect match

   `bool operator==(const MockPointer<T>& rhs);`
2. making the constructor taking `T*` explicit

   `explicit MockPointer(T*);`

I made a live example at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73300327b4fcfac8 which you can play with; try removing the `explicit` keyword from the constructor, which reproduces the issue you describe in your question and comments. Allowing the compiler too much latitude for implicit conversions will often result in ambiguity as the compiler simply has too many ways to make a function call happen.

You may also get some results from removing one or more implicit conversions.

Comment: Now it broke instantiation+assignment. `int i; MockPointer<int> TestIntPointer = &i;` - `error: conversion from 'int*' to non-scalar type`. What is the right way to perform that (other than splitting it into two lines; instantiation and assignment)

Comment: `MockPointer<int> TestIntPointer {&i};`, `MockPointer<int> TestIntPointer (&i);` or `auto TestIntPointer = MockPointer<int>{&i};` would work. `explicit` constructors are not considered using copy-initialization.

Comment: Also, note that `MockPointer<int> TestIntPointer = &i;` is *not* instantiation and assignment, it's copy-initialization.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Ah, the syntactic sugar that changes the meaning of the operator depending on context. I really had hoped mr. Stroustrup took a lesson from misters K&R, when they fixed early C's behavior: `int a=1, b=2; if(a&b){ /* condition satisfied */ }  int c = a&b; if(c){ /* condition not satisfied */}` (& changing meaning between boolean and logical depending on context).